# Checking for a Value in a Table and Updating It via a RestAPI

Tags: c#, rest

I wanted to check for a value in a table and update it if it  fits certain conditions but I don't think I'm doing it right:

```
public void UpdateUsertoActive(string email)
    {
        var token = ApiLogin();
        string filter = $"Email_Address = '{email}'";
        var contactstatus = new List<string>
        {"Contact_Status_ID"};
        var activestatus = _ministryPlatformRest.UsingAuthenticationToken(token).Search<MpMyContact>(filter, contactstatus);
        if (activestatus.Equals(2))
        {
            activestatus = _ministryPlatformRest.UsingAuthenticationToken(token).UpdateRecord("dbo.Contacts", GetContactIdByEmail(email), contactstatus);
        }
        else
        {//do nothing}
    }
```

I want to check for the Contact_Status_ID; `if it is == 2` then change it to `1` else do nothing.

This is the Contact Model from which the Contact_Status_ID comes from:

```
namespace MinistryPlatform.Translation.Models
{
    [MpRestApiTable(Name = "Contacts")]
    public class MpMyContact
    {
        public int? Address_ID { get; set; }
        public string Address_Line_1 { get; set; }
        public string Address_Line_2 { get; set; }
        public int? Contact_Status_ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of information missing here. What does .Search() actually return? Using .Equals to check for equality has its pitfalls when the types are not clear. e.g. activestatus could be a string and your are checking it against an integer. .Equals would return false. Hint: Try to not use 'var' when the return type is not 100% clear. :)

Comment: You didnt provide enough information. What is the problem? What are the methods definitions?

Comment: what use you have for `contactstatus`? you create an empty list and send as paramater . What is the return for `.Search()`

Comment: Search should return a row based on "filter"

Comment: a row? or an integer? why you declare it as var instead of integer? Still you havent tell us what is the problems you have.     Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Searching for value in a specified column which in this case is "Contact_Status_ID"

Comment: You have filter variable but you are not using it anywhere and you expect the result based on filter. Did you debug the code and checked if it is following your logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make this a lot simpler by swapping out all the code to find the status and just issue an update statement in a procedure. Something like this. Essentially what your code is doing is running a query to see if the row exists in that status. If it does, run a second query to update it. It is much less resource intensive to just update it.

```
create procedure UpdateUsertoActive
(
    @EmailAddress varchar(500)
) as 
    set nocount on;

    Update YourTable
    set Contact_Status_ID = 2
    where Contact_Status_ID = 1
        and Email_Address = @EmailAddress
```